# xpath syntax for selecting the text after <strong> tag

Tags: xpath

```
<div class="article_details">
<h1>Product name is</h1>
<div class="left">
<ul class="article_list">
<li>
<strong>art. nr.:</strong>
VS7896
</li>
<li>
<b>Shipping time</b>
: 1-3 Days
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I used `//DIV[@class='left']/UL[1]/LI[1]` but the result is "**art. nr.: VS7896**".

Please help me with the correct XPath to select just "**VS7896**".

Answer (score 5):

To select the text after `<strong>`, use

```
//strong/following-sibling::text()[1]
```